# Freemarker - replace & with &amp;

Tags: freemarker

If i have the `&` symbol in some field  (from a db, cannot be changed), and i want to display this via  freemarker... but have the display (from freemarker) read `&amp;`, what is the way to do so?

To reiterate, I cannot change the value before hand (or at least, I don't want to), i'd like freemarker to "unmark" &.

To double re-iterate, this is a value that is being placed with a *lot* of other xml. The value itself is displayed on its own, surrouded by tags... so something like

```
<someTag>${wheeeMyValueWithAnAmpersand}<someTag>
```

As a result, i don't want *all* ampersands escaped, or the xml will look funny... just that one in the interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh goodness.

I see the problem: the code was written like this:

```
<#escape x as x?xml>
<#import "small.ftl" as my>
<@my.macro1/>
</#escape>
```

and at which i'd assumed that the excape would excape all the calls within it - it is certainly what the documentation sort of implies

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html

```
<#assign x = "<test>"> m1>
  m1: ${x}
</#macro>
<#escape x as x?html>
  <#macro m2>m2: ${x}</#macro>
  ${x}
  <@m1/>
</#escape>
${x}
<@m2/>
```

> the output will be:

```
&lt;test&gt;
m1: <test>
<test>
m2: &lt;test&gt;
```

However it appears that when you *import* the file, then this isn't the case, and the escape... escapes!

SOLUTION:
http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/

the above link details how to solve the problem. In effect, it comes down to loading a different FreemakerLoader, one that wraps all templates with an escape tag.

```
class SomeCoolClass implements TemplateLoader {
    //other functions here
    @Override  
    public Reader getReader(Object templateSource, String encoding) throws IOException {  
        Reader reader = delegate.getReader(templateSource, encoding);  
        try {  
            String templateText = IOUtils.toString(reader);  
            return new StringReader(ESCAPE_PREFIX + templateText + ESCAPE_SUFFIX);  
        } finally {  
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);  
        }  
    }
```

which is a snippet from the link above.  You create the class with the existing templateLoader, and just defer all the required methods to that.

Comment: The referred manual page explains this. `escape` only applies to the expressions that are between the `escape` tags in the *source code*. It's like if somebody types the `?html` for you, but only in the lines that are literally between the `escape` tags. If you think about it, it would be nearly useless/ummanageable if it's applied on the lines that are *called* from there. Because, when you write a macro or to-be-included template, it should do the same regardless of where it's called from.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.24 no `TemplateLoader` "hack" is needed anymore. There's a setting called `output_format`, which specifies if and what escaping is needed. This can be configured both globally, and/or per-template-name-pattern utilizing the `template_configurations` setting. The recommend way of doing this is even simpler (from the manual):

> [...] if the
>   `recognize_standard_file_extensions` setting is `true` (which is the
>   default with the `incompatible_improvements` setting set to 2.3.24 or
>   higher), templates whose source name ends with ".ftlh" gets "HTML"
>   output format, and those with ".ftlx" get "XML" output format